# Stop Windows from launching Edge welcome window when a new user logs in

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

How can I disable the Windows Edge welcome window from appearing when a new user is created in Windows 10?

*Just to be clear, the Edge window appears by itself when a new user is created. Do not confuse this with the "First Run page", which is triggered when a user opens Edge for the first time. I did not open anything. I just logged on a newly created user.*

If possible I would prefer registry hack instead of GPO edit. Why? Because I have made a bunch of registry tweaks already and I would like to stick to the method. But of course if that is the only solution I guess I do not have a choise.

[image]

**Alternative 1**

What I have tried so far is to run the following commands in PowerShell ISE as admin in one account and then make a new admin account to see if the Window pops up again.

```
reg load HKLM\DEFAULT c:\users\default\ntuser.dat
reg add "HKLM\DEFAULT\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Main" /v PreventFirstRunPage /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg unload HKLM\DEFAULT
```

This does not seem to work even when I can confirm that the registry change has been made.

**Alternative 2**

I tried enabling the "Prevent the First Run webpage from opening on Microsoft Edge" GPO but that does not workeither. Reading the description it seems like this only applies once users actually open Edge.

> If you disable or don't configure this setting, employees will see the First Run page **when opening** Microsoft Edge for the first time.

**Alternative 3**

I also tried making a logon script with the following content as described [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/disable-welcome-to-microsoft-edge-page-and-default-browser-prompt-in-windows-10-1607/#using-a-powershell-logon-script)

```
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge" -type Directory
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Firstrun" -type Directory
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main" -type Directory
# These two values removes the Edge Welcome screen
new-itemproperty "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\FirstRun" -Name "LastFirstRunVersionDelivered" -Value 1 -Type DWORD -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
new-itemproperty "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main" -Name IE10TourShown -Value 1 -Type DWORD -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
# This registry entry disables the prompt to make Edge the default browser
new-itemproperty "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main" -Name "DisallowDefaultBrowserPrompt" -Value 1 -Type DWORD -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
```

**Alternative 4**

Tried going to Settings -> System -> Notifications & Actions -> and turned off "Show me the ‘Windows welcome experience after updates and occasionally when I sign in to highlight what’s new and suggested". Still didn't help.

Note that I do make new accounts after every time I try something new.

I am running Windows 10 Pro v.1803 with all the latest updates.

Comment: Did you google it? https://www.google.com/search?q=Disable+Microsoft+Edge+welcome+screen+in+Windows+10&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&oq=Disable+Microsoft+Edge+welcome+screen+in+Windows+10&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Are you serious? Yes I did. None of the registry suggestions I found works, hence my question here.

Comment: GPO edit would modify the registry.  Don’t understand the reason you don’t want to use a GPO

Comment: Yes I am, put the research you have done and what you have tried in your Question, that way we don't go in circles trying to help you. We don't read minds here.

Comment: This information is readily available with a google search, and it does work because I use it myself. What you probably forgot to do was modify the registry of the “default” user so that it doesn’t show for “new” users. But you need to put what you’ve tried in your question. We’re here to help but not do the work for you. Because as of now this seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Sorry about that. Was in a hurry but that is no excuse. I have added what I have tried now.

Comment: Feels kind of unjustified that I continue to get downvotes after I have tried to solve this issue for six hours straight after I have provided information on what I have tried. I have tried literally every solution mentioned on the internet as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

**Posting this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation.**

The field of your issues lies to the OOBE (out of box experience) topic, I haven't directly found a reference to Edge in the [Customize the Out of Box Experience (OOBE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-oobe) page but there is a possibility that it is configurable (i.e. you're going to have to search about it).

I would recommend that you try on a virtual machine with snapshots so you can rewind whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
REG LOAD HKLM\TempHive "C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT"
REG ADD 
"HKLM\TempHive\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager" 
/v SubscribedContent-310093Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
REG UNLOAD HKLM\TempHive
```

This solved it for me
credits to https://www.itninja.com/blog/view/disable-windows-welcome-experience-dialog-during-os-deployments